How can I skip edge function running if env is set?
I created a Netlify edge function in a nuxt.js project and called it my-edge-function.ts.
I'd need to run the edge function only if RUN_EDGE_FUNCTION env is set.
Since running edge functions is money consuming i want to avoid placing the condition inside the edge function.
What would be a good approach? is it doable using netlify.toml?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
